# SQL Server - C# - ASP.NET : error 52 connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.NET MVC and I get this error after running `update-database` command when connecting to SQL Server:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to the server. The server was not found or the server is unreachable. Verify that the instance name is correct and SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - A Local Database Runtime installation was not found. Make sure SQL Server Express is properly installed and the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnection": "Data Source=localhost,1440;Initial Catalog=DbMvcKamp;User ID=sa;Password=Cem090909.;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
}
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder what led you to tag Selenium?

Comment: Well it looks like your database cannot be found. Are you sure the connectionstring is correct?

Comment: Are you sure about the port number 1440? Usually Sql Server responds on port 1433. (And there is no need to specify a port number unless you have changed it)

Comment: @steve docker kullanıyorum port1440

Comment: I truly hope that is not your actual sa password

Comment: I would recommend going to SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager and double checking the enabled port number(s) displayed in Protocols for SQLEXPRESS > TCP/IP. 1433 is the port number for the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance and dynamic port numbers are typically in the 40000+ range. Port 1440 would be a very unusual choice. Also doublecheck what `localhost` resolves to on the command line - you may need to use `Data Source=127.0.0.1,1440;` if `localhost` resolves to the IPv6 address, `::1`, for example.

Comment: please share docker info.

Comment: try to get connection string from server explore in visual studio check link below
[link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/)

Comment: @ProSheta gave this error 
This connection cannot be tested because the specified database does not exist or is not visible to the specified user